# test fails with "argument expected" when comparing "("

Tags: ksh

Can someone please explain why this command returns an error (on Solaris ksh):

`if [ "(" = "(" ]; then echo 1;fi;

ksh: test: argument expected`

The same using bash is OK, and echoes "1" as expected
Also, using [[ ]] is OK.

The problem seems to be the first "("

Comment: Sadly, that code works for my ksh.

Comment: Interesting, maybe it's a bug in my ksh (Solaris 10)

Comment: The above code works fine on the ksh that comes with OSX

Answer (score 1):

That command seems to work on my ksh.

However, IIRC in ksh it's recommended to use [[ ]] instead of [ ]. So for a portable solution, I suggest you write it as:

```
if [[ "(" = "(" ]]; then echo 1; fi;
```

Do note however that [[]] is subtly different from [] in that wildcard expansions are not done. See http://www.bolthole.com/solaris/ksh-builtins.html#test

**Update**

For better portability to different shells, I tend to use the  built-in *test* command which in ksh should have the exact same effect as [[]].

```
if test "(" = "("; then echo 1; fi
```

Comment: I usually try not to use [[ ]], because it's NOT portable (to 
bash, anyway)

Comment: oops, my mistake. not to sh anyway

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you change the double quotes to single quotes -- i.e.,

```
if [ '(' = '(' ]; then echo 1;fi;
```

**EDITED TO ADD**: I've just been able to recreate the problem with a Digital UNIX ksh. Single quotes don't work either on this platform, however escaping the brackets does work:

```
if [ '\(' = '\(' ]; then echo 1;fi;
```

According to the man page for ksh, it states:

> The following characters have a
>   special meaning to the shell and cause
>   termination of a word unless
>   quoted:
>
> ```
>    ; & ( ) | ^ < > <newline> <space> <tab>
> ```

...and goes on to define more parsing rules. It seems that the ( is being interpreted as a special character even when quoted (oddly), hence the requirement for escaping. If you type "`set -x`" at the command line before you try your if, you'll see exactly what the shell is trying to do sent to stderr preceded with a '+' sign, which may help the tracing; e.g.:

```
$ set -x
$ if [ '(' = '(' ]; then echo 1;fi;
+ [ ( = ( ]
ksh: test: argument expected
$
$ if [ '\(' = '\(' ]; then echo 1;fi;
+ [ \( = \( ]
+ echo 1
1
$
```

It may be that it depends on the ksh implementation as well -- e.g., ksh-88 vs ksh-93 and later. On Digital UNIX, the implementation is ksh-88.

Comment: thanks - at least I'm not going mad, and someone else sees the problem. I can't escape it because the actual code used is in a file read loop, and a variable is used. i.e. if [ "$var" = "test" ]

Comment: Joe -- I've just tried doing this: [ '\'"$var" = '\\(' ]  ... which seems to work. If I remove the '\' that precedes "$var" it falls over as expected. Now I don't know what the contents of $var is in you instance, but you might be able to come up with a solution based on this?

Comment: OK, thanks - contents of var is "(", hence the problem. I'm just going to go for the [[ ]] solution - probably less confusing for future maintainers.